# Error when moving between hiding and un-hiding user forms

Tags: excel, vba

At the moment I have 23 userforms, called "Question1, Question 2, etc"

[image: Right now I have 23 userforms, called "Question1" "Question2" etc....]

Each form contains a question and the user has 2 buttons to move between questions and then gets to the last question where all answers are submitted.

At the moment the buttons to move from one screen to another work fine except for when I want to move from question 17 to question 18

```
'Option 1
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("70").Value = True
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D70").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D70").Font.Bold = True
If OptionButton1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D70").Value = False
If OptionButton1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D70").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If OptionButton1.Value = False Then Worksheets("Results").Range("D70").Font.Bold = True

Me.Hide
Question18.Show
```

And at the moment I get an error saying

> "Method or data member not found"

on the line

```
Question18.show
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you just asked?

Comment: Why use all these forms? Why not just one form and change the content?

Comment: Yes, but now the issue is not when hiding the current userform but rather when trying to move into a new one

Comment: @Tom I wanted to be able to save the current answers in case the user wants to go back to another question and review the answers

Comment: Well assign it to a variable - use an array or collection or write it back to a sheet

Comment: I'd suggest you use a Multipage control. It's usuallly a lot simpler for this sort of thing.

Comment: Range("70") can't be correct